# Extract multiple values from string in ansible

Tags: ansible

I am a newbie in ansible, I have a string in following format:

```
str = "

aaaa.abc1=value1

aaaa.abc2=

aaaa.def1=value2

aaaa.ddd1=

"
```

Spaces between the string is basically a blank line.

I am trying to extract following values in 2 separate list

`list1=['abc1','def1'] list2=['value1','value2']`

How can I achieve it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        list1: "{{ list1|d([]) + [item.0.split('.').1] }}"
        list2: "{{ list2|d([]) + [item.1] }}"
      with_together:
        - "{{ _keys }}"
        - "{{ _vals }}"
      when: item.1|length > 0
      vars:
        _lines: "{{ str.splitlines()|select|list }}"
        _keys: "{{ _lines|map('regex_replace', '(.*)=(.*)', '\\1')|list }}"
        _vals: "{{ _lines|map('regex_replace', '(.*)=(.*)', '\\2')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  list1:
  - abc1
  - def1

  list2:
  - value1
  - value2
```

Comment: Thanks Vladimir.